# how to redirect correctly using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

While I am redirecting to localhost/creator it says object not found.Error 404

```
# Set the routes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/creator/$1 [L,R=301]

#Set the sites route
RewriteRule ^sites([a-z/]*)$ /sites/$1 [L]

#Set the javascript route
RewriteRule ^javascript([a-z/]*)$ /javascript/$1 [L]

#Set the themes route
RewriteRule ^themes([a-z/]*)$ /themes/$1 [L]

#Set the images route
RewriteRule ^images([a-z/]*)$ /images/$1 [L]

#Set the html route
RewriteRule ^html([a-z\-/]*)$ index.php?route=$1 [QSA,L]

#Set the application route
RewriteRule ^([a-z\-/]*)$ index.php?route=$1 [QSA,L]

#Set the application default route
RewriteRule ^([a-z\-/]*)$ index.php [QSA,L]

# Default Index Page
DirectoryIndex index.php

# Protect htaccess file
<files .htaccess="">
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
```

this is the .htaccess code that i am using for my site . and i am not familiar with htaccess. so please help me to do this.

Comment: `localhost/creatar` are you sure there is no spelling mistake?

Comment: no. it is localhost/creator

Comment: but here you are asking "While I am redirecting to `localhost/creatar`".

Comment: oh. i am sorry. it is actually creator. i put wrong in quostion. it is actually localhost/creator

Comment: i think you need rewritebase for this instead of redirecting you are doing here that every request to localhost will be server by creater directory right?

Comment: Your first redirect rule will cause redirect loop. If you're getting 404 then this .htaccess is not even being used.

Comment: is there anything wrong with that htaccess rules??

Comment: Yes and as I wrote first redirect rule will cause redirect loop if URL is `http://localhost/`